# Show ruler based on editor.wordWrapColumn, without hardcoding the number

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basically, I want to be able to say (in `settings.json`):

```json
{
  ...
  "editor.rulers": [
    ${config:editor.wordWrapColumn}
  ]
}
```

The issue is that this variable can only be expanded in a `string`, but `editor.rulers` requires a list of `number`s.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Show ruler based on editor.wordWrapColumn, without hardcoding the number [...] Is this possible?

Not that I know of.

There's [a feature-request (#30609)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30609) on the VS Code GitHub to get a setting to achieve what you're looking for, but it's currently closed and [not being looked at](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30609#issuecomment-345746573). You can show your support by giving it a thumbs up reaction there, or you can consider writing a different proposal if you think you have a better idea.